# PHP: Abstract classes vs interfaces

Tags: php

What is the difference and when/why is it better to use one over the other? They seem to do similar things with abstract classes providing more flexibility.

Comment: Actually this might answer it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960729/abstract-class-vs-interface?lq=1

Comment: Mine is regarding php, if there is any difference in oo design principles between .net (your link) and php (my question).

Comment: No, same. Abstract classes can implement stuff, but you can have multiple unrelated interfaces. A dog (specific) is an animal (abstract), but it can bite (interface), it is a host for fleas (interface), it is a pet (interface).